# How to fix this Statement to increment the specified variable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a problem regarding in my codes where in the fields are not auto incrementing; I will posting the codes below :

```
else
{
    using (conn = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("ProfilingDB")))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string GetLastRow = "SELECT CONCAT(MAX(YEAR(applied_date)), " +
                    "MAX(MONTH(applied_date)) , MAX(DAY(applied_date))) as applied_date FROM personal_info"; //get last row of request date"

        using (cmd = new SqlCommand(GetLastRow, conn))
        {
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string AppliedNow = DTAppliedYear + DTAppliedMonth + DTAppliedToday;
                DTApplied = (dr["applied_date"].ToString());

                if (AppliedNow == DTApplied)
                { //compare the last row request date to datetime.now

                  string MaxAppliedNumber = "SELECT MAX(applicant_number) as applicant_number FROM personal_info";  // get max applied applicant

                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(MaxAppliedNumber, conn))
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {

                            applicantNumber = Int64.Parse(dr["applicant_number"].ToString());
                            applicantNumber++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string appliedNum = AppliedNow + "000"; //set ticket number and add string 0000
                    applicantNumber = Int64.Parse(appliedNum);

                    db.Insert_info(applicantNumber, txtbox_fname.Text, txtbox_lname.Text, txtbox_midname.Text, txtbox_address.Text, cb_gender.Text, dt_bday.Value.Date,
                    int.Parse(txtbox_age.Text), txtbox_email.Text, Int64.Parse(txtbox_contact.Text), applying_for, DateTime.Now);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

"I expected the output to increment in applicant_number field"

Comment: [1]: https://imgur.com/a/vCCLVVF  here is the link of the possible output,

Comment: First if you have additional information you should edit the question rather than adding a comment.  Second when possible it's better to copy and paste text instead of using an image.

Comment: @juharr thanks for editting I was going to edit it btw, but anyway thanks.

Comment: You should definitely look into your date logic. Are you sure you want to mix up all your date's like that? What will happen if the maximum day was the 31st (of January) and the maximum month was 2 (February)? What do you want to do with the 31st February?

Comment: nvoigt, yes . i guess there is no problem with it as it gets its data from the other field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try identity(1,1), from 1 to increase 1 when insert a new column, in your sql database. When you insert a new row, just skip the id column.

```
create table #table1
(
id int identity(1,1),
name varchar(10)
)

insert into #table1
values ('Test1'), ('Test2'), ('Test3'), ('Test4')

select * from #table1
```

[image]

If you've already created a table, you can right click your table name in Object Explorer if using SQL Server, click "Design", then choose your id column.
[image]